# passing column list as argument in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have couple of large `.tsv` files and trying to extract the data from it. we are passing column list as argument, however we are getting duplicate `ValueError: Duplicate names are not allowed.`.

However, we have no issues if we pass the values as `names=['coming_from','article','referrer_type','n']`

Here is my code

```
import datetime,json,pyodbc
import pandas as pd

class LoadData:
    def __init__(self,colname):
        self.colsname=colname

    def _read_file_extract_col_data_convert_data_into_json(self):
        _filepath_name = r"E:\PythonScripts\PyCharm\files\source\clickstream-enwiki-2018-12.tsv"
        col_names='['+self.colsname+']'
        for chunk in (pd.read_csv(_filepath_name, delimiter="\t", header=0,names=col_names, 
        chunksize=1,mangle_dupe_cols=True)):
        json_chunk = chunk.to_json(orient="records", force_ascii=True, default_handler=None)
        print(json_chunk)

list=[]
collist="'coming_from'","'article'","'referrer_type'","'n'"


p1=LoadData(','.join(collist))
p1._read_file_extract_col_data_convert_data_into_json()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:/PythonScripts/PyCharm/PythonScripts_withPyCharm/DataIngestionScripts/File_To_JSON.py",
> line 54, in 
> p1._read_file_extract_col_data_convert_data_into_json()   File "E:/PythonScripts/PyCharm/PythonScripts_withPyCharm/DataIngestionScripts/File_To_JSON.py",
> line 17, in _read_file_extract_col_data_convert_data_into_json
> for chunk in (pd.read_csv(_filepath_name, delimiter="\t", header=0,names=col_names, chunksize=1,mangle_dupe_cols=True)):   File
> "C:\python_customize_install_location\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 686, in read_csv
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "C:\python_customize_install_location\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 449, in _read
> _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))   File "C:\python_customize_install_location\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 415, in _validate_names
> raise ValueError("Duplicate names are not allowed.") ValueError: Duplicate names are not allowed.

Comment: Are you aware that you defined ```pandas``` as ```pdcol``` but use ```pd``` in ```pd.read_csv```?

Comment: it was a typo , thanks for pointing it out

Comment: `col_names` seems to be a string while pandas expect a list.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem with your code is how you handle the list of column names.
Initially it is a **single string**.
Even after you run `col_names='['+self.colsname+']'` this is **still** a single string
(enveloped in square brackets), whereas it should be a **list** of column names.

The second problem is that when you invoke *read_csv* with *header=0* and
*names=...* parameters together, it means that:

- row *0* does contain column names,
- but you **override** them with your own *names* (a list).

My experience indicates that the column list passed here in *names* should
have the same length as the number of actual data columns, otherwise various
"side effects" can occur.

My suggestion is to change your code to something like below:

```
class LoadData:
    def __init__(self, colnames):
        self.colnames = colnames

    def _read_file_extract_col_data_convert_data_into_json(self):
        _filepath_name = r"Input.tsv"
        i = 0
        for chunk in (pd.read_csv(_filepath_name, delimiter="\t",
                header=0, names=self.colnames, chunksize=1)):
            print(f'chunk {i}:'); i += 1
            print(chunk)
            json_chunk = chunk.to_json(orient="records")
            print(json_chunk)

collist = ['coming_from', 'article', 'referrer_type', 'n']
p1 = LoadData(collist)
p1._read_file_extract_col_data_convert_data_into_json()
```

Note that:

- I passed my input file name as *_filepath_name*. In your version
  change it to your file name.
- I added some additional trace printouts, drop them in the final version.
- Passing *mangle_dupe_cols* has no sense here, as you override the
  existing column list with a new list, without repetitions.
- To keep the code concise, in the invocation of *to_json* I dropped
  *default_handler* and *force_ascii*, as their default values are just
  *None* and *True*.

I prepared my input file (*Input.tsv*) as:

```
aa  bb  cc  dd
a1  a2  a3  a4
b1  b2  b3  b4
c1  c2  c3  c4
```

The result I got was:

```
chunk 0:
  coming_from article referrer_type   n
0          a1      a2            a3  a4
[{"coming_from":"a1","article":"a2","referrer_type":"a3","n":"a4"}]
chunk 1:
  coming_from article referrer_type   n
1          b1      b2            b3  b4
[{"coming_from":"b1","article":"b2","referrer_type":"b3","n":"b4"}]
chunk 2:
  coming_from article referrer_type   n
2          c1      c2            c3  c4
[{"coming_from":"c1","article":"c2","referrer_type":"c3","n":"c4"}]
```

Another reason that your code failed can be that you have **more** columns in
the input file than in *names* list.
In such a case:

- the list passed in *names* overrides only **final** column,
- but initial columns have no name (they will be omitted in *to_json*.

Comment: hmmm, is seem you are good in explained answers, super!

Comment: Valdi_Bo ,  Thanks a lot for the help and clarification.